# LNK1181: Cannot open input file 'boost_python.lib' in windows

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

Trying to make MultiNEAT work in windows:http://multineat.com/

Installed boost 1.58 with boost python in windows and I am using visual studio as compiler.

First I did:

```
set INCLUDE = \boost_root;%INCLUDE% 
set LIB = \boost_root\stage\lib;%LIB%
set LIBPATH = \boost_root\stage\lib;%LIBPATH%
```

In command line calls

```
python setup.py install
```

error is LNK1181:

```
Cannot open input file 'boost_python.lib' in windows
```

I checked boost_root\stage\lib folder there is no file called boost_python.lib
but there are

```
libboost_python-VC110-MT-1_58.lib   and
libboost_python-VC110-MT-1_58.lib
```

Here is the setup.py file in MultiNEAT

```
setup(name='MultiNEAT',
      version='0.2',
      py_modules=['MultiNEAT'],
      ext_modules=[Extension('_MultiNEAT', ['src/Genome.cpp',
                                            'src/Innovation.cpp',
                                            'src/NeuralNetwork.cpp',
                                            'src/Parameters.cpp',
                                            'src/PhenotypeBehavior.cpp',
                                            'src/Population.cpp',
                                            'src/PythonBindings.cpp',
                                            'src/Random.cpp',
                                            'src/Species.cpp',
                                            'src/Substrate.cpp',
                                            'src/Utils.cpp'],
                             libraries=['boost_python',
                                        'boost_serialization'],
                             extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-march=native',
                                                 '-DUSE_BOOST_PYTHON',
                                                 '-DUSE_BOOST_RANDOM'
                                                 ])
                   ])
```

Wondering did I include the LIB/LIBPATH wrong or I should change the name of the built libraries, really struggling, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove 'boost_python' and 'boost_serialization' from setup.py. Boost should know which libraries to link to.

Comment: @cgohlke so after I remove libraries=['boost_python', 'boost_serialization'],the error became LNK1104: cannot open file 'boost_python-vc110-mt-1_58.lb'

Comment: It looks like you have built the static boost libraries. Try add `/DBOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` to the `extra_compile_args`.

Comment: @cgohlke I also add '/EHsc' to the 'extra_compile_agrs' then it works like a charm, thank you so much for your help!